# Command \c@abspage already defined

Tags: footnotes

I am trying to restart the numbering of my footnotes on each page. The package `\perpage` conflicts with my current setup. It seems that the `footmisc` has a similar issue since I received the same error message. Is there another option that works with xelatex?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[perpage,para]{footmisc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{extramarks}

\setmainlanguage{syriac}
\setmainfont[BoldFont={DejaVu Serif Bold}]{Serto Antioch Bible}
```

Comment: Do not show only snippets. Always make a small but complete example. Do not use local fonts in such an example unless it is relevant. And tell which tex system you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example seems to work, if you load `zref-abspage` (loaded automatically by `bibi`) earlier:

```latex
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{zref-abspage}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[perpage,para]{footmisc}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{extramarks}

\setmainlanguage{syriac}
\setmainfont{Serto Antioch Bible}
\begin{document}
\mbox{}
\end{document}
```

But I've not tested, if the footnotes are numbered per page, because you've not shown a minimal working example with footnotes.

An alternative would be to use LuaLaTeX instead of XeLaTeX. There the problem does not occur, because LuaLaTeX does not need `bidi`, which is often a source of problems.

Comment: That worked. Thank you for your help! I tried with LuaLaTeX, but it messed up the direction of the document. I was able to use XeLaTeX to get it to compile.

Comment: a good catch. But it is a bit unfair to claim that this problem is due to bidi. It is zref which isn't careful enough here. I will adapt it so that it not longer uses \newcounter if abspage is already defined.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer The problem with `bidi` is, that it has to load several additional packages and also has to redefine a lot of macros. And this can lead to unexpected problems. In the example case, it is because `bidi` loads `zref-abspage`, which is a problem if counter `abspage` is already defined. This does not happen, if `bidi` is not loaded, e.g., using LuaLaTeX instead of XeLaTeX. The average user doesn't care for which package causes the problem. He/she is more interested in: It works with LuaLaTeX. That's all I meant. Yes, live is not fair.

Comment: Just did. Thanks again for your help!